# How to get rect of rotated view or layout in android

Tags: android, android-studio, rotation, angle

User can rotate or move view group. While moving need to check boundary condition based on parent view width and height. so if there is no rotation i can check boundary condition. But if there is rotation applied on view group. then its rect get changed. so i need to find out
bounding rect after rotation.

I am using setRotation method of android sdk to rotate view.

Example:
Before Rotation
[image]

After Rotation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can catch roration event in this method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // get new scales
}
```

Comment: Issue is not related to device orientation change. Basically we have have some custom views with different shapes(Rectangle, Round) on the screen. User can rotate each shape as per his needs. Suppose there is rectangle shape with rect(50, 100, 200, 100). User rotate this shape 90 deg. so after rotation new bounding rect would be (100, 50, 100, 200) . I want to know what is bounding rect of view in respect of parent after rotation applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your view's `x` and `y` coordinates like this

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
@Override public void onGlobalLayout(){
    int [] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];
    view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
}
```

Here, you get the location of your view whether it's rotated or not in `x` and `y` relatively.